# How do you get a GDImage from a chillerlan qtcode

Tags: php, qr-code

I use chillerlan qr_code to generate a qrcode in php.

```
$gdImage = (new QRCode ($options)) ->render('https://www.youtube.com/');
```

I can echo the qrcode on the screen as a qrcode.
I can also printit as a  string.
BUT  the following call returns false.

```
$gdImage2 =@imagecreatefromstring($gdImage);
```

How can I create a GDImage of  my qr Code?

Thanks,

Comment: The manual has an example of doing that: https://php-qrcode.readthedocs.io/en/main/Built-In-Output/QRGdImage.html